# In Optim function, print out parameter input in R

Tags: r, function, optimization

I have a function called est_Bt()

```
est_Bt = function(pars)
{
    exp_Bt <- rep(NA,length(prawn_df$Catch))
    exp_Bt[1] <- pars[4]
    for(i in 2:length(prawn_df$Catch))
    {
        exp_Bt[i] <- max(exp_Bt[i-1] + exp_Bt[i-1]* (pars[1]/pars[3]) * (1-((exp_Bt[i-1]/pars[2])^pars[3])) - prawn_df$Catch[i-1],100)
    }### Not we put the max to either bt+1 or 100 so the stock doesn't go extinct.
    cpue_obs <- prawn_df$Catch/prawn_df$Effort
    pred_q <- log(cpue_obs/exp_Bt)
    series <- 0:(nrow(prawn_df)-1)
    q_int <- as.vector(lsfit(series,pred_q)$coefficients)[1]
    q_stat <- as.vector(lsfit(series,pred_q)$coefficients)[2]
    qinc_int <- exp(q_int)
    qinc_stat <- exp(q_stat)
    q <- rep(NA, length(series))
    q[1] <- qinc_int
    for(i in 2:length(q)){
        q[i] <- q[i-1]* qinc_stat
    }
    pred_cpue <- pred_bt* q
    sum((log(cpue_obs) - log(pred_cpue))^2)
}
```

The Function is not important itself what I would like help is when evaluating pars using the function optim() I was wondering if there is a command for printing out trialing parameters. The function gives the sum of squares for applying a fisheries surplus model to Catch effort data.

```
est_Bt(c(0.2,30000, 0.0000000001, 50000))
[1] 159.2381
est_Bt(c(0.32,27000, 0.0000000001, 45000))
[1] 67.45901
```

when I use optim however I get

```
optim(c(0.32,27000, 0.0000000001, 45000), est_Bt)
Error in lsfit(series, pred_q) : NA/NaN/Inf in 'y'
In addition: Warning message:
In lsfit(series, pred_q) : 26 missing values deleted
```

My thoughts on this are that it is testing a parameter value that is nonsense and the function is failing. And I'm sure that I should know my equation to penalise for ridiculous parameter values. But I thought that if optim could print out the parameter values each trial then it would help me explore the parameter interactions in my model?

Chairs Cyrill

Comment: Just add `print(pars)` right after your function begins. Is that all you need?

Comment: But optim requires a single output from the function to minimise if I add that

Comment: I get the error    Error in optim(c(0.2, 30000, 50000, 1e-10),est_Bt) :objective function in optim evaluates to length 4 not 1

Comment: I meant put it here: `est_Bt <- function(pars) {print(pars); exp_Bt<- rep(NA, length(prawn_df$Catch)) ...` Your function should have the exact same return value

Comment: I'm sorry You are Right thank you. I put that at the of the function not the beginning.

Comment: If that's all you needed, i've added that as answer. Please consider accepting it (clicking the checkmark) if that did exactly what you wanted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to print the "current" set of parameters your function is evaluating, just add a `print` to the beginning of your function

```
est_Bt <-function(pars)
{
    print(pars)
    exp_Bt <- rep(NA,length(prawn_df$Catch))
    exp_Bt[1] <- pars[4]
    ...
}
```

That will send the values to the screen.